# Linked List in x86 assembly(MASM)

Tags: beginner, linked-list, assembly, x86

Module 1:

```
;*******************************************************************************
; A generic Linked List ADT for any datatype.
;
; Author: William 

                .386 
                .MODEL  flat, stdcall
                .STACK  4096
                PUBLIC  push_front, print_list

; Win32 function prototypes and synonyms

GetProcessHeap  PROTO
HeapAlloc       PROTO,  hHeap:DWORD,
                        dwFlags:DWORD,
                        dwBytes:DWORD
GetStdHandle    PROTO,  nStdHandle:DWORD
WriteConsoleA   PROTO,  hConsoleOutput:DWORD,
                        lpBuffer:PTR DWORD,
                        nNumberofCharsToWrite:DWORD,
                        lpNumberOfCharsWritten:PTR DWORD,
                        lpReserved:DWORD

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE       equ  -11
HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY        equ  00000008h  

                .CODE
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; print_list(hptr, fptr)
; 
; Prints nodes of given linked list
;
; Entry:
  hptr          EQU     [ebp + 8]                       ;head ptr 
  fptr          EQU     DWORD PTR[ebp + 12]             ;std_call func ptr that 
;                                                        prints list data type
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print_list:
                push    ebp
                mov     ebp, esp
                sub     esp, 12
                push    eax
                push    edx
                push    ebx

                ; Locals variables
arrow           EQU     [ebp - 4]                       ;string "-> " 
                mov     DWORD PTR arrow, '  >-' 

nstr            EQU     [ebp - 8]                       ;string "NULL"
                mov     DWORD PTR nstr, 'LLUN'  

wrtn            EQU     [ebp - 12]                      ;num of chars written
                mov     DWORD PTR wrtn, 0

                ; loop while(node != NULL)
                mov     ebx, hptr
                jmp     endL3
L3:             
                ; print (node->data)
                push    [ebx]                   
                call    fptr                                    

                ; print "-> "
                INVOKE  GetStdHandle, 
                        STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE               
                mov     edx, eax        
                INVOKE  WriteConsoleA, edx,
                                       ADDR  arrow,     
                                       3,
                                       ADDR  wrtn,
                                       0 

                ;node = node -> next    
                mov     ebx, [ebx + 4]

endL3:          test    ebx, ebx        
                jnz     L3

                ;print "NULL"
                INVOKE  GetStdHandle, 
                        STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE               
                mov     edx, eax        
                INVOKE  WriteConsoleA, edx,
                                       ADDR nstr,
                                       4,
                                       ADDR wrtn,
                                       0 

                pop     ebx
                pop     edx
                pop     eax
                mov     esp, ebp
                pop     ebp
                ret     8

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; push_front(headptr, dataptr, dsiz)
; 
; Adds a new linked list node to the front of a linked list.
; 
; Entry:
  hptr          EQU     [ebp + 8]                       ;DW ptr to headptr
  dptr          EQU     [ebp + 12]                      ;DW data ptr
  dsiz          EQU     [ebp + 16]                      ;DW data size in bytes  
  node_size     EQU     00000008h
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
push_front:
                ; set up stack save regs
                push    ebp
                mov     ebp, esp
                push    eax
                push    ebx
                push    ecx
                push    edx
                push    esi

                ; allocate memory for new node
                call    GetProcessHeap
                INVOKE  HeapAlloc, eax,
                                   HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 
                                   node_size
                mov     ebx, eax                        ;save node in ebx

                ; allocate memory for new data
                call    GetProcessHeap
                INVOKE  HeapAlloc, eax,
                                   HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 
                                   dsiz

                ; save into new node
                mov     [ebx], eax                      ;node->data = new data
                mov     eax, hptr
                mov     eax, [eax]                      ;dereference hptr
                mov     [ebx + 4], eax                  ;node->next = hptr 

                ; loop copying data into newly allocated 
                ; memory byte per byte 
                mov     edx, dsiz
                mov     esi, dptr
                xor     ecx, ecx                        ;loop counter                   
                jmp     endL1
L1:             mov     al, [esi + ecx] 
                mov     [ebx + ecx], al
                inc     ecx
endL1:          cmp     ecx, edx
                jl      L1

                ; hptr = new node
                mov     eax, hptr
                mov     [eax], ebx

                ; restore regs clean up stack
                pop     esi
                pop     edx
                pop     ecx
                pop     ebx
                pop     eax
                pop     ebp
                ret     12

                END
```

Module 2

```
;*******************************************************************************
; LL_main.asm is the main module that demonstrates the Linked_List ADT
;
; Author: William 

                .386 
                .MODEL  flat, stdcall
                .STACK  4096
                EXTERN  push_front:near, 
                        print_list:near

; Win32 API function prototypes and synonyms
ExitProcess     PROTO,  dwExitCode:DWORD 
GetStdHandle    PROTO,  nStdHandle:DWORD
WriteConsoleA   PROTO,  hConsoleOutput:DWORD,
                        lpBuffer:PTR DWORD,
                        nNumberofCharsToWrite:DWORD,
                        lpNumberOfCharsWritten:PTR DWORD,
                        lpReserved:DWORD

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE       EQU     -11
NULL                    EQU     0

                .CODE
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; print_hex(num)
;
; prints a 32 bit unsigned hexadecimal number to the console
;
; Entry:
  num           EQU     [ebp + 8]                       ; DW unsigned hex number
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print_hex:
                ; set up stack frame, save regs
                push    ebp
                mov     ebp, esp 
                sub     esp, 4
                push    eax
                push    ebx
                push    edx
                push    esi

                ; local variable for # of chars written by WriteConsoleA
nWrtn           EQU     [ebp - 4]
                mov     DWORD PTR nWrtn, 0                      

; This loop repeatedly divides the number by 10h, converts the remainder
; to its corresponding ASCII code, and then saves the char to the stack 
                mov     eax, num                
                mov     ebx, 10h                        ; the divisor, 10h
                xor     edx, edx                        ; clear edx
                xor     esi, esi                        ; esi = num of chars
L1:             div     ebx                             ; div num by 10h

                ;convert remainer to ASCII code
                ;if edx > 9, add 7
                cmp     edx, 9
                jle     endIf1
                add     edx, 7
endIf1:
                ;add char '0' to num
                add     edx, '0'

                ;put char on stack
                dec     esp                             ; allocate stack space 
                mov     [esp], dl                       ; save char to stack
                inc     esi                             ; inc num of chars              
                xor     edx, edx                        ; clear edx

                ; end of loop L1                
                test    eax, eax                        ; loop while num != 0   
                jnz     L1

                ; print out chars from the stack
                mov     edx, esp
                INVOKE  GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE 
                mov     ecx, eax
                INVOKE  WriteConsoleA, ecx,
                                       edx,
                                       esi,
                                       ADDR nWrtn,
                                       NULL

                add     esp, esi                        ; restore esp                   ; 

                ;clean up stack, restore regs
                pop     esi
                pop     edx
                pop     ebx
                pop     eax
                mov     esp, ebp
                pop     ebp
                ret     4

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; main() 
;
; creates a linked list of integers and prints them to the screen.
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main:
                mov     ebp, esp
                sub     esp, 8

                ; local variables
head_ptr        EQU     [ebp - 4]                       ; head of list
                mov     DWORD PTR head_ptr, 0

hex_int         EQU     [ebp - 8]                       ; a starting int
                mov     DWORD PTR hex_int, 10fd134h

                ; loop L2 adds 6 numbers to list
                xor     esi, esi                        ; loop counter
L2:                     
                ; add hex_int to front of the list
                push    4
                lea     eax, hex_int
                push    eax
                lea     eax, head_ptr
                push    eax 
                call    push_front

                inc     esi
                add     DWORD PTR hex_int, 14768h

                ; end of L2     
                cmp     esi, 6                          ; while (esi < 6)       
                jl      L2                      

                ; print out list
                push    print_hex
                push    head_ptr
                call    print_list

                mov     esp, ebp
                INVOKE  ExitProcess, 0
                END     main
```

Output:

> 116363C-> 114EED4-> 113A76C-> 1126004-> 111189C-> 10FD134-> NULL

This is a minimal implementation of a Linked List that took me a long time to figure out and get working. It only allows you to create a list, push to it, and print it out. There is no way to destroy the list, so the program leaks memory.

I'm looking for ALL criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *print_hex* procedure preserves almost all registers, yet you didn't preserve the `ECX` register that you nonetheless used in `mov ecx, eax`.

Maybe an idea to use `pushad` and `popad`:

```
num         EQU     [ebp + 36]
nWrtn       EQU     [ebp - 4]
;-----------------------------------------------
print_hex:
    ; set up stack frame, save regs
    pushad
    mov     ebp, esp
    ...
    mov     esp, ebp
    popad
    ret     4
```

Instead of initializing the local variable with `sub esp, 4` `mov DWORD PTR nWrtn, 0` you can simply write:

```
    xor     eax, eax
    push    eax
```

The hex conversion should not be done using division at all! Remember that dividing by 16 is just shifting 4 times to the right.
Next is an optimized version:

```
        mov     ebx, 'A' - 10
        mov     ecx, num
        xor     esi, esi      ; esi = num of chars
L1:     mov     eax, ecx
        and     eax, 15       ; Keep lowest nibble
        mov     edx, '0'
        cmp     eax, 9
        cmova   edx, ebx      ; Only for [10,15] will EDX become 55
        add     eax, edx      ; Either [0,9] + 48 or [10,15] + 55
        dec     esp           ; allocate stack space 
        mov     [esp], al     ; save char to stack
        inc     esi           ; inc num ofchars              
        shr     ecx, 4        ; loop while num != 0   
        jnz     L1
```

Allocating **single bytes** on the stack (any number of bytes from 1 to 8), leaves the stackpointer un-aligned! Always keep `ESP` dword aligned.

```
        mov     edx, esp
        and     esp, -4       ; Keep ESP dword aligned
        INVOKE  GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
```

To restore `ESP` use `EBP`

```
        mov     esp, ebp
        popad
        ret     4
```

---

> ```
>         xor     esi, esi     ; loop counter
> L2:                     
>         ...
>         inc     esi
>         cmp     esi, 6       ; while (esi < 6)       
>         jl      L2
> ```

Since `ESI` holds a counter that will always be positive, I think using the *unsigned* conditional jump would be more appropriate.

```
        cmp     esi, 6         ; while (esi < 6)       
        jb      L2
```

Better still, count downward and shave off the `cmp` instruction. You can do this because the `ESI` value here isn't used for anything else than the loop count.

```
        mov     esi, 6
L2:
        ...
        dec     esi
        jnz     L2
```

---

The loop that copies memory a byte at a time can be simplified if the copying starts at the high end. And because it's a safe assumption that *dsiz* will always be positive non-zero you can code a Repeat-Until loop instead of a While loop.

```
; loop copying data into newly allocated memory byte per byte 
        mov     edx, dsiz      ; 4 is your example
        mov     esi, dptr
L1:     dec     edx
        mov     al, [esi + edx] 
        mov     [ebx + edx], al
        jnz     L1             ; Flags still set according to "dec edx"
```